# Comparing timestamps with mybatis, postgresql

Tags: java, timestamp, alfresco, mybatis

I'm using mybatis to query on my postgres DB, My problem is the comparaison between timestamps, i think it is not working properly since it doesn't retrun the needed results even it is not throwing any exception.
Here is my code

```
<select id="select_count" parameterType="map" resultType="map">
        select count(*) as count, TO_CHAR(created_on, #{xaxis}) as xaxis,state 
        from my_table
        where 1 = 1
        <if test="fromdate != null"> and created_on &gt;= #{fromdate} </if>
        <if test="todate != null"> and created_on &lt;= #{todate} </if>
        <if test="state != null"> and state = #{state} </if>
        GROUP BY xaxis, state
</select>
```

and here is my java code

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getStatesCount(Date fromDate,
                Date toDate, String state, String xAxis) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("fromdate", fromDate);
        params.put("todate", toDate);
        params.put("state", state);
        params.put("xaxis", "yyyy-mm-dd");
        List<Map<String, Object>> sqlResults = (List<Map<String, Object>>) template.selectList(SELECT_COUNT, params);
        return sqlResults;
    }
```

and this is the code for creating my_table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
   id INT8 NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('my_table_seq'),
   state VARCHAR(20),
   created_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```

I know that my table has many rows with the 'created_on' prop set to , let's say, today's date. But when i pass my two date params or even one one of them , the select query doesn't return any data.

So how to query properly with timestamps and `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: i think i found the problem : the spelling of date params were not written correctly, All is fine now, thx

Comment: What query does MyBatis generate? (Enable SQL logging in MyBatis or enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf`)

Comment: If you think this question might be useful to others please post your own answer and accept it once the new-user timer on Stack Overflow lets you; I'll upvote.

Comment: it is my fault, i didn't pay attention to the names of parameters, it works like a charm, BTW how to enable mybatis logging?

Comment: I don't use MyBatis so I'd have to look it up in the documentation, Stack Overflow search or on Google, same as you.

Comment: Sorry Craig Ringer, i am quite new to SOF, i edited my post to include the correct answer and now i m looking how to accept it

Comment: No worries. You don't edit your post to add the answer, you post an answer to the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer . For me this is available as an edit box down the bottom of the page, after the question and comments. It is possible this is disabled by a timer for you as Stack Overflow has some annoying (but arguably necessary) limitations on new users to manage spam and abusive behaviour. I'd post the answer myself but I want to give you the score for making the effort of writing a good question and following up on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am posting the correct answer.

Here is my code

```
<select id="select_count" parameterType="map" resultType="map">
    select count(*) as count, TO_CHAR(created_on, #{xaxis}) as xaxis,state 
    from my_table
    where 1 = 1
    <if test="fromdate != null"> and created_on &gt;= #{fromdate} </if>
    <if test="todate != null"> and created_on &lt;= #{todate} </if>
    <if test="state != null"> and state = #{state} </if>
    GROUP BY xaxis, state
</select>
```

and here is my java code

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getStatesCount(Date fromDate,
            Date toDate, String state, String xAxis) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("fromdate", fromDate);
    params.put("todate", toDate);
    params.put("state", state);
    params.put("xaxis", "yyyy-mm-dd");
    List<Map<String, Object>> sqlResults = (List<Map<String, Object>>) template.selectList(SELECT_COUNT, params);
    return sqlResults;
}
```

and this is the code for creating my_table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_table_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id INT8 NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('my_table_seq'),
  state VARCHAR(20),
  created_on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
);
```